# Mvc 3 model auto binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ViewModel that I want to autobind to another ViewModel on post.

Eg. if I have

```
public class ViewModelA{
    public string Stuff {get;set;}
}

public class ViewModelB{
    public string MyStuff {get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For display/rendering purposes, I want the partial to bind to ViewModelA, because it's a much simpler object and hence it'll hopefully be much more reusable since creating an interactive view is a costly proposition.

However, I need all the form information on the page **on post**. I suppose I could widen the controller action to take both ViewModelA and ViewModelB, and then do additional logic to assign ViewModelA property into ViewModelB, but is there a cleaner, more declarative way to do this?

I guess I'm wondering if I could tag ViewModelA, with some attribute like this:

```
 [Bind(Prefix = "ViewModelB", Include = "MyStuff")]
```

I know I can do it at the action level, but can I inject this logic at the ViewModel level?

Also would be nice if Razor follows a more CQRS approach. eg.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(target => target.Property, model => model.Property2)
```

So that on render, the textbox is initialized with Property2 value, but on post, it's posted to target.Property.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you inherit `ViewModelB` in `ViewModelA`?

```
public class ViewModelA : ViewModelB
{
     public string Stuff {get;set;}
     // etc.
}  

public class ViewModelB
{     
    public string MyStuff {get;set;}
    // etc.
}
```

Then in your Controller method, just specify the wider `ViewModelB` and the model binding should still map everything.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(ViewModelB model)
{
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I supposed that would be one way to get about it, but I detest class inheritance and IsA relationship in general. Also what happen when There're 3 or more ViewModels and I want 2 of them to go to ViewModelB? Or what if ViewModelA has some "display" properties that are irrelevant? Inheritance is more headache than they're worth. I like to keep the ViewModel POCO and loosely coupled as much as possible.

Comment: Detest class inheritance?  Why are you even using .NET?

Comment: @cadrell0 How do you handle 2 different view models that needs to be mapped into one ViewModel with class inheritance? And how do you keep the target ViewModel clean from unneeded properties? Hint: You can't.

Comment: @Alwyn: You can't flag a comment as off topic.  And "favor composition over inheritance" != "inheritance is evil".  Try to keep your comments polite, please.

Comment: @Will WTF is the purpose of this: "Why are you even using .NET" <-- Why don't he keep his comment civil. I'm standing my ground, inheritance used in this way for a ViewModel is retarded. Sorry. Again learn friggin'  OO design.

Comment: @Alwyn: First off, you're overreacting.  If you "detest" one of the central tenets of OOP, it is a valid question to ask why you would choose a language which is object oriented.  Also, calling someone's answer "retarded" and demanding that they "learn friggen' OO design" isn't civil.  This is the second time I've had to point this out.  Please read our [faq#benice] on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more straightforward if both your models had the same property names for the purpose of binding, whether you achieve this by inheritance, or by having helper properties whose business is to set the real property names.

This would make it more clear that ViewModelB is expecting to be able to handle certain property names differently and make the view template less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify `ViewModelB` as a parameter to the action that handles your form posts.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModelB newWidget) {
    // handle creation of widget... all information on the form pertaining to viewmodelB will be
    // available in newWidget
}
```

It doesn't matter what model was used to generate the view; as long as there are form field names that match up to property names in ViewModelB, the Model Binder will handle it for you.